# Getting image from UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I want to get the image frm `imagepickercontroller`.But my code doesn't have any effect
Here is the code..

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    imageview.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"]];
```

Answer (score 9):

You can try this code to access an Image returned from the picker

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    UIImage* originalImage = nil;
    originalImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    if(originalImage==nil)
    {
        originalImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    }
    if(originalImage==nil)
    {
        originalImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerCropRect];
    }
  //At this point you have the selected image in originalImage
    [self saveImageToDocumentDirectory:originalImage];
}
```

Comment: First of all, links to similar questions should be commented not answered. Secondly, the reason why his code isn't working is obviously the 'imageNamed' and also probably the @"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"

Comment: Thank you Phlibbo for pointing out the link stuff , however it was for taking the hint and not for redirecting to the question I have mentioned

Comment: Link to hint seems to be dead

Comment: @MichałW. Thank  you for pointing that out. I have updated my answer. Is there anything specific with the current code other than the dead link ?

Answer (score 7):

Try

```
imageview.image = (UIImage*) [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
```

Answer (score 5):

Updated for **Swift 5**, the following will safely unwrap the `UIImage`.

```
// This uses the full key value
guard let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage else { return }

// This uses only the info key value for shorter code
guard let image = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage else { return }
```

Comment: Renamed in modern Swift to `info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage]`

Answer (score 0):

Updated for Swift 5, the following will safely get the UIImage

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    var newImage: UIImage
    if let possibleImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage] as? UIImage {
        newImage = possibleImage
    } else if let possibleImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {
        newImage = possibleImage
    } else {
        return
    }
    
    m_imgView.image = newImage
    
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score -1):

just try this

```
imageview.image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
```