# Camera with library button in iOS7

Tags: ios, camera, camera-roll

I have two questions :) :
- in my app, I would like to post pictures that were taken from the camera, or the library.
But the default camera doesn't show the library button, and I would like to use this feature.
Do you know how can I integrate the library button as in original camera from iOS 7 ?

[image: Library button from iOS7]
My second question is: when I took the picture, can I go to an other view to show the image and do what I want like adding a title for example, or do I have to stay in the actual view ?

thank you for your time !

Comment: For your first part, you're probably looking for an ActionSheet. Apps will often use this to determine if you're adding from the library or taking a live picture. This is because you don't have access to modifying the UIImagePickerViewController to add the 'library' button on the camera overlay. You'd have to do some custom coding to your own camera to do that. As for your second question - when using the UIImagePickerViewController, you get direct access to the image they took or chose. So you can pass this to another VC to do what you want with it!

Comment: Thank you for your help, now I have some ideas to get on with it ;)

Comment: No problem! Let me know if you have any issues, UIImagePickerViewController is super easy to deal with, should take you a few hours after a brief tutorial

Comment: Hi :)
I used the ActionSheet and it works well, I can choose between my camera and my library, but I have trouble passing my image in another view :/ 
I can't figure out how to do this with UIImagePickerViewController, do you have any clue ?

Comment: You can use something like the answers provided in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7766211/getting-image-from-uiimagepickercontroller to get access to the image. From there, if your view is in another VC then instantiate the VC and do `[vc setUserImage:originalImage]`, then push the VC.

Comment: I tried some stuff, but none of them worked, I made a new post if you want to take a look : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24164618/uipickerview-uiimage-and-segue

Comment: Looks like you got an answer :). Best of luck on your project!